# Worker framework for Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, subprocess, multiprocessing

Are there any generic worker frameworks for Amazon EC2 available for Python? Something, for which you could just say "run this Python task X" and it will automatically assign the task to one of worker process on the servers from a server pool and report back after the task has been executed?

- Describe task in a Python (class, script, etc.) - in this case extract information from an audio file
- Have some kind of controller for which you give the task and files (in my case through HTTP interaction) - the controller knowns the pool of EC2 servers it can use for running the task
- The controller allocates an EC2 server for the task - each server could contain N amount of worker processes (not threads, this is Python after all...)
- The task is executed on the server and the progress (0...100% done) is reported back to the controller which in turn can report it back to the user

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Elastic MapReduce](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/)

Comment: Can MapReduce do anything complex as custom Python virtual machines? I know I need to manually add native Python extensions, especially ffmpeg.